# How to get maximum values of all the keys in the list of dictonary

Tags: python

I am facing an issue with getting the maximum of each key in an list of dictionary.
for example I have a list of dictionaries ls:

```
ls = [{'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':7}, {'a':5, 'b': 2, 'c':6}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c':8}]
```

The output should be `{a = 5, b = 4, c = 8}`

I have tried a number of methods, for example:

`maxx= max(ls, key=lambda x:x['a'])`

but this and every other method is returning me the sub-dictonary having the maximum "a" value, b and c is not getting considered

can anyone please help me out on this

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck…?

Comment: tried number of methods, for example maxx= max(ls, key=lambda x:x['a']) but this and every other method is returning me the sub-dictonary having the maximum "a" value, b and c is not getting considered

Comment: Use simple loops first, then try to find clever solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming all your dictionaries have the same keys:**

```
{k: max(d[k] for d in ls if k in d) for k in ls[0].keys()}
```

outputs `{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}`

I use the keys of the first dictionary `ls[0]`, supposed to be the same as the others

**If your dictionaries don't have the same keys,** here is a one liner solution
(Thank you @Timus for the improvements in the comments)

```
{k: max(d[k] for d in ls) for k in set().union(*(d.keys() for d in ls)) }
```

`set().union(*(d.keys() for d in ls))` concatenates all keys and select the set of unique keys.
`max(d[k] for d in ls if k in d)` just select the max value if the key is in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but this one works:

```
ls = [{'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':7}, {'a':5, 'b': 2, 'c':6}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c':8}]

#initialize with first dict
final_dict = ls[0]

for mydict in ls:
    if mydict['a']>final_dict['a']:
        final_dict['a'] = mydict['a']

    if mydict['b']>final_dict['b']:
        final_dict['b'] = mydict['b']

    if mydict['c']>final_dict['c']:
        final_dict['c'] = mydict['c']

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, This can be one of the ways But my keys are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant solution, but small.

```
keys = ls[0].keys()
res = dict()
for key in keys:
    maxvalue = max(ls, key=lambda x:x[key])
    res[key] = maxvalue[key]
-> {'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This get the work done

```
maxii = {}
for item in ls:
  for key, value in item.items():
    if key not in maxii:
        maxii[key] = value
    else:
        maxii[key] = max(maxii[key], value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty output dictionary then iterate over the remaining items:

```
ls = [{'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':7}, {'a':5, 'b': 2, 'c':6, 'e':7}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c':8}]

output = {}

for d in ls:
    for k, v in d.items():
        output[k] = max(output.get(k, float('-inf')), v)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 8, 'e': 7}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer after looking at this, since this is much better! Also handles inconsistent keys in elements in `ls`, as requested by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first dictionary contains all the keys, use:

```
print({k:max(x[k] for x in ls) for k in ls[0].keys()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest code, but it works:

```
ls = [{'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':7}, {'a':5, 'b': 2, 'c':6}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c':8}]
complete_dict = {}
for d in ls:
    complete_dict.update(d)

unique_keys = {key for key in complete_dict.keys()}
max_dict = {key: max(ls, key=lambda x: x.get(key, 0)).get(key) for key in unique_keys}
print(max_dict)
```